# Feasibility of Baum-Welch algorithm

Tags: probability-theory, algorithms

Baum-Welch is an instantiation of the more general Expectation-Maximization (EM) algorithm. But recently when I learned about it I couldn't figure out where the Maximization step is used. Because the Baum-Welch algorithm give me a sense of just iterating between computing some intermediate variables according to old parameters and updating parameters according to computed intermediate variables. Out of the reason, I searched this problem online, but I only find [this article](https://stephentu.github.io/writeups/hmm-baum-welch-derivation.pdf) useful to me. My problem is a step in the derivative process troubled me(it's shown in the figure below). Could you please explain it to me? I asked my professor and she couldn't help me.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMhBA.jpg)

Comment: Probably they set the derivatives of the conditional expectation to $0$ in the maximization step instead of directly maximizing the conditional expectation.

Comment: Yes, but I can't  understand one of the deduction steps in setting the derivatives of the Lagrange function to 0. Could you explain why it works? It's shown in the figure. Thanks!